# How to add another filtering category to List.js?

Tags: javascript, filtering

I am using this library: http://listjs.com/

I need to add another category to filter by, so I added like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /* 
    * LOVELY THINGS
    */

    var templates = {
        valueNames: [ 'name', 'description', 'category' ]
    };

    var featureList = new List('lovely-things-list', templates);

    $('#filter-games').click(function() {
        featureList.filter(function(values) {
            if (values.category == "Game") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#filter-NewCategory').click(function() {
        featureList.filter(function(values) {
            if (values.category == "NewCategory") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });


    $('#filter-beverages').click(function() {
        featureList.filter(function(values) {
            if (values.category == "Beverage") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#filter-none').click(function() {
        featureList.filter(function(values) {
            return true;
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

And button like this:

```
<li class="btn" id="filter-NewCategory">Only show New Category</li>
```

Then the filtering does not work correctly. First button for first category works, second adds some results, third works sometimes etc.

Maybe someone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute the filtering function gets is a single item.
You need to do the following to make the comparison:

```
$('#filter-games').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.values().category == "Game") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And for resetting the filter you can simply do

```
featureList.filter();
```

Full example here: 
http://pastebin.com/UPB095pk

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your second .click is binding to #filter-games when you mean to bind to #filter-NewCategory?

Try changing the code to read:

```
 $('#filter-NewCategory').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(values) {
        if (values.category == "NewCategory") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
```